# How do I save my dual monitor configuration?

Tags: multiple-monitors, xfce, hdmi

My system uses dual HDMI monitors and until this upgrade, they were working as expected. Now, however, whenever the PC goes to sleep, and is reawakened or even if the monitors themselves go into their own sleep mode, the system reverts to *mirrored* rather than *extended* and monitor 2 is out of position. I have to go into the settings each time to fix it. Of course, each time all my desktop icons get moved over from display 1 to display 2 too.

I am running Ubuntu Studio 22.10 with the Xfce4 desktop.

Comment: You can save display profiles: https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-settings/display#advanced

Comment: I've been using the Advanced settings to configure it, then pressing Apply. When it prompts separately to confirm the changes, I select to save. Still, it reverts even if I shut off the monitors at night or if the go to sleep.

Comment: Please add any additional, pertinant details to your original question. Thanks.